# Сохранить аудиопоток из интернета

Tags: android

Как реализовать запись (сохранение) аудиопотока из интернета? Есть ссылка на файл типа .mp3, при нажатии на кнопку "Старт" нужно начать сохранение проигрываемого файла на телефон, а при нажатии на "Стоп" остановить запись. В какую сторону копать? Примеров подобных не нашел.

Comment: Просто берёте любую либу (хоть стандартную) и делаете `GET` запрос на адрес файла. Файл будет в ответе сервера.

Comment: А стандартная как называется?

Comment: Я не знаю) Никогда не использовал) Советую `OkHttp`. А вообще - вопрос не очень понятен. У вас уже как-то воспроизведение сделано? И надо только загрузить? Если вы `MediaPlayer` используете, то, может, там уже и есть такая фича из коробки. Вроде оно одновременно грузит и играет. Возможно можно файл итоговый и вытащить чрез неё.

Comment: Может вот это подойдёт: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033301/3212712. А то не понятно - вам файл скачать и проиграть, скачать проигрываемый файл или менеджер загрузки файла с прогрессом и прочим сделать надо. Не очень понятно каких вам ссылок давать. Попробуйте локализовать проблему и сформулировать вопрос точнее

Comment: У меня сделано проигрывание через exoplayer. Теперь хочу добавить функцию записи проигрываемого аудио

Comment: Ну, коли сам плеер не позволяет это сделать, то качайте стандартными средствами файл и проигрывайте его плеером из локального файла

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.